# Generic methods in .NET cannot have their return types inferred. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, type-inference

Given:

```
static TDest Gimme<TSource,TDest>(TSource source) 
{ 
    return default(TDest); 
}
```

Why can't I do:

```
string dest = Gimme(5);
```

without getting the compiler error:

`error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Whatever.Gimme<TSource,TDest>(TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

The `5` can be inferred as `int`, but there's a restriction where the compiler won't/can't resolve the return type as a `string`.  I've read in several places that *this is by design* but no real explanation.  I read somewhere that this might change in C# 4, but it hasn't.

Anyone know why return types cannot be inferred from generic methods?  Is this one of those questions where the answer's so obvious it's staring you in the face?  I hope not!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The general principle here is that type information flows only "one way", from the *inside* to the *outside* of an expression.  The example you give is extremely simple. Suppose we wanted to have type information flow "both ways" when doing type inference on a method `R G<A, R>(A a)`, and consider some of the crazy scenarios that creates:

```
N(G(5))
```

Suppose there are ten different overloads of N, each with a different argument type. Should we make ten different inferences for R? If we did, should we somehow pick the "best" one?

```
double x = b ? G(5) : 123;
```

What should the return type of G be inferred to be?  Int, because the other half of the conditional expression is int?  Or double, because ultimately this thing is going to be assigned to double?  Now perhaps you begin to see how this goes; if you're going to say that you reason from outside to inside, *how far out do you go*? There could be *many* steps along the way. See what happens when we start to combine these:

```
N(b ? G(5) : 123)
```

Now what do we do?  We have ten overloads of N to choose from. Do we say that R is int? It could be int or any type that int is implicitly convertible to. But of those types, which ones are implicitly convertible to an argument type of N? Do we write ourselves a little prolog program and ask the prolog engine to solve what are all the possible return types that R could be in order to satisfy each of the possible overloads on N, and then somehow pick the best one?

(I'm not kidding; there are languages that essentially *do* write a little prolog program and then use a logic engine to work out what the types of everything are. F# for example, does way more complex type inference than C# does. Haskell's type system is actually Turing Complete; you can encode arbitrarily complex problems in the type system and ask the compiler to solve them.  As we'll see later, the same is true of overload resolution in C# - you cannot encode the Halting Problem in the C# type system like you can in Haskell but you can encode NP-HARD problems into overload resolution problems.) (**See below**)

This is still a very simple expression. Suppose you had something like

```
N(N(b ? G(5) * G("hello") : 123));
```

Now we have to solve this problem multiple times for G, and possibly for N as well, and we have to solve them *in combination*. We have five overload resolution problems to solve and *all* of them, to be fair, should be considering both their arguments and their context type. If there are ten possibilities for N then there are potentially a hundred possibilities to consider for N(N(...)) and a thousand for N(N(N(...))) and very quickly you would have us solving problems that easily had billions of possible combinations and made the compiler very slow.

This is why we have the rule that type information only flows one way. It prevents these sorts of chicken and egg problems, where you are trying to both determine the outer type from the inner type, and determine the inner type from the outer type and cause a combinatorial explosion of possibilities.

Notice that type information does flow both ways for lambdas! If you say `N(x=>x.Length)` then sure enough, we consider all the possible overloads of N that have function or expression types in their arguments and try out all the possible types for x. And sure enough, [there are situations in which you can easily make the compiler try out billions of possible combinations](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012004329/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/26/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-four.aspx) to find the unique combination that works. The type inference rules that make it possible to do that for generic methods are exceedingly complex and make even Jon Skeet nervous. [This feature makes overload resolution NP-HARD](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012091758/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/03/28/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-five.aspx).

Getting type information to flow both ways for lambdas so that generic overload resolution works correctly and efficiently took me about a year. It is such a complex feature that we only wanted to take it on if we absolutely positively would have an amazing return on that investment. Making LINQ work was worth it. But there is no corresponding feature like LINQ that justifies the immense expense of making this work in general.

---

**UPDATE**: It turns out that you *can* encode arbitrarily difficult problems in the C# type system. C# has nominal generic subtyping with generic contravariance, and it has been shown that you can build a Turing Machine out of generic type definitions and force the compiler to execute the machine, possibly going into infinite loops. At the time I wrote this answer the undecidability of such type systems was an open question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968075/88656 for details.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out how to distill this information from one of your related articles on lambda type inference in LINQ, but you beat me with an actual answer much better than I could have written through translation.

Comment: @Eric, with the co/contravariance features you added to the C#4.0 would it be simple to get a reduced syntax where you could infer the input type parameters and still be explict with the output types?  Something like `TDest Gimme<in TSource, out TDest>(TSource source)` with the usage of `var returned = Gimme<out string>(5);`

Comment: Even using something like named parameters would be handy... usage `var returned Gimme<TDest:string>(5);` I'm wondering because I have seen several locations where I would like to provide anonymous types for the input but be able to define the output type. This typically ends with be going to `Func<...>` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You have to do:

```
string dest = Gimme<int, string>(5);
```

You need to specify what your types are in the call to the generic method.  How could it know that you wanted a string in the output?

System.String is a bad example because it's a sealed class, but say it wasn't.  How could the compiler know that you didn't want one of its subclasses instead if you didn't specify the type in the call?

Take this example:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control dest = Gimme(5);
```

How would the compiler know what control to actually make?  You'd need to specify it like so:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control dest = Gimme<int, System.Windows.Forms.Button>(5);
```

Comment: I think the question was "why can't the compiler infer the return type?" rather than "how can I explicitly declare the return type?"

Comment: @Dave - I'm feeling a little dense: for your second example, why would the compiler have to know what control to actually make at all? Wouldn't `Gimme<int, System.Windows.Forms.Control>` be a legitimate usage?

Comment: @Jeff Instead of a class, what about interface? What would Gimme<int, IDisposable>() return?

Comment: I think the bigger issue is that the left side of an assignment never specifies the exact type in C# -- yes, they *could* have made the design decision to infer the type from the left hand side in the language, but in general it wouldn't be too hard to imagine how that could potentially get hairy as the class structure for System.Windows.Forms.Control evolves over time.

Comment: @Dave - that's a good point (that the left side doesn't normally specify the exact type), and may be the answer. @Adrian - since interfaces are reference types too, Gimme<int, IDisposable>() would return null.

Comment: @Iain: Now that Eric Lippert has weighed in, I almost feel like I should delete my post :)

Comment: @Dave, please don't.  Eric's answer requires understanding where the 'casual developer' (whatever that is) can easily go 'ahhh' from your `Control` example much easier than `N(G(5))`.  IOW, let both answers stand. =)

Answer (score 5):

Calling `Gimme(5)` ignoring the return value is a legal statement how would the compiler know which type to return?

Comment: Isn't that just the reason we wouldn't try to infer it *in those cases*? Why would that prevent us from trying to infer it in cases where we *do* specify the return value's type?

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Think about it, what is the code going to do if you call it like the above.  What is it going to use for the type of TDest within the method?

Comment: @Paddy, the point Jeff makes is that the compiler could easily choose to fail on the above while still inferring the return type in other cases.  Remember, the issue is compiler behavior not runtime behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I use this technique when I need to do something like that:

```
static void Gimme<T>(out T myVariable)
{
    myVariable = default(T);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Gimme(out int myVariable);
Print(myVariable); //myVariable is already declared and usable.
```

Note that inline declaration of out variables is available since C# 7.0

Comment: This is the best way I've found to make a generic infer it's type from what it's assigning it's result to. The alternative is something like:
`myVariable = Gimme<int>();` which I suppose isn't much different.

Answer (score 1):

This was a design decision I guess. I also find it useful while programming in Java.

Unlike Java, C# seems to evolve towards a functional programming language, and you can get type inference the other way round, so you can have:

```
var dest = Gimme<int, string>(5);
```

which will infer the type of dest. I guess mixing this and the java style inference could prove to be fairly difficult to implement.

Comment: I'm of mixed feelings about this.  I think I would rather do `Dictionary<string,string> x = new var()` or just `Dictionary<string,string> x = new()` than `var x = new Dictionary<string,string>()`, if only so that reading the left side of the code gives me the types of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is supposed to return one of a small number of types, you could have it return a class with defined widening conversions to those types.  I don't think it's possible to do that in a generic way, since the widening ctype operator doesn't accept a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReturnString : IReq<string>
{
}

public class ReturnInt : IReq<int>
{
}

public interface IReq<T>
{
}

public class Handler
{
    public T MakeRequest<T>(IReq<T> requestObject)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

var handler = new Handler();
string stringResponse = handler.MakeRequest(new ReturnString());
int intResponse = handler.MakeRequest(new ReturnInt());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's often better to add some explanation to your code. What have you done/changed that solved the problem? See [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)