# Is there any way to use C# methods directly as delegates?

Tags: c#, syntax, delegates, lambda

This is more of a C# syntax question rather than an actual problem that needs solving. Say I have a method that takes a delegate as parameter. Let's say I have the following methods defined:

```
void TakeSomeDelegates(Action<int> action, Func<float, Foo, Bar, string> func)
{
    // Do something exciting
}

void FirstAction(int arg) { /* something */ }

string SecondFunc(float one, Foo two, Bar three){ /* etc */ }
```

Now if I want to call `TakeSomeDelegates` with `FirstAction` and `SecondFunc` as arguments, As far as I can tell, I need to do something like this:

```
TakeSomeDelegates(x => FirstAction(x), (x,y,z) => SecondFunc(x,y,z));
```

But is there a more convenient way to use a method that fits the required delegate signature without writing a lambda? Ideally something like `TakeSomeDelegates(FirstAction, SecondFunc)`, although obviously that doesn't compile.

Comment: "although obviously that doesn't compile" ... that should compile :)

Comment: woops, I really have no idea what I was doing wrong before, but it seems to work just fine now. I guess this is a pretty silly question :S

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time guys... I'm also unsure of what answer to mark as correct... should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is something called '[method groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c)'.  With these, you can replace one line lamdas, such as:

was:

```
TakeSomeDelegates(x => firstAction(x), (x, y, z) => secondFunc(x, y, z));
```

after replacing with method groups:

```
TakeSomeDelegates(firstAction, secondFunc);
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! I'm going to accept this because of the link explaining why this works :)

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the parens on the function names.

```
        TakeSomeDelegates(FirstAction, SecondFunc);
```

EDIT:

FYI Since parens are optional in VB, they have to write this...

```
 TakeSomeDelegates(AddressOf FirstAction, AddressOf SecondFunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will accept names of method groups where a delegate is needed, as long as it can figure out which overload to choose, you don't need to build a lambda.  What is the exact compiler error message you're seeing?

Comment: Bear in mind that it can only figure out 'in' parameters, i.e. it can't resolve the type that a method returns:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why

Comment: Since you can't overload method groups based on return type, this isn't a problem.  (You can overload `operator implicit` and `operator explicit` on return type, but these can't be named as method groups).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is called Method Group, and more precise example of that is...

```
static void FirstAction(int arg) { /* something */ }

static string SecondFunc(float one, Foo two, Bar three) { return ""; }


Action<int> act1 = FirstAction;
Func<float, Foo, Bar, string> act2 = SecondFunc;


TakeSomeDelegates(firstAction, secondFunc);
```

In this way you can use Method Group.