# Shorthand when calling generic methods in c#

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

If I have the method

```
void foo<T>(T bar){}
```

I can successfully call it like this:

```
string s = string.Empty;
foo(s);
```

As I imagine the compiler/runtime can infer the type,

However If I change the method to this:

```
T foo<T,T2>(T2 bar){...}
```

Then I must call it in 'full', specifying both the input parameter type and the return type:

```
string s = string.Empty;
foo<int,string>(s);
```

Is there a way I can shorthand this so I dont need to specify the input parameter(s) type?
I.E.

```
foo<int>(s);
```

Thanks

Comment: To clarify "I imagine the compiler/runtime can infer the type": the type inference in your example is handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always rewrite your method to:

```
void foo<T, U>(U bar, out T baz)
{
    baz = default(T);
}
```

if you really want the type inference... Now:

```
string s = string.Empty;
int i;

foo(s, out i);
```

will work just fine.

Also, see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why) for an excellent answer by Eric Lippert as to why you can't have what you want!

EDIT: I realise I didn't actually answer your question...

> Is there a way I can shorthand this so I dont need to specify the
>   input parameter(s) type?

Simply put... No.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way for compiler to infer the `T` from the example from usage. As far as it cannot be done automatically, you need to provide it.

There are no "optional" type parameters in C# and no shorthands.

Comment: Doesn't this kind of inference work with Expressions? If so, why not with methods?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what you mean under "this kind of inference work with Expressions". Maybe, you can post an example?

Comment: I've just been having a go and there's always a compilation error whatever way I try, but I was thinking of delegates or lambda. Doesn't the Func<TResult, T> do exactly this?

Comment: Actually not exactly this. When you write `x => return x.Property;` the `T` is either predefined from previous method chain, or you should set it explicitly.

Comment: Actually yes you're right. With a lambda, there's no access to the value of `T` (and if you don't need it, why would you be using it in the method?) So although we can't see the body of `foo`, we can safely say it won't work if you tried using that body as a lambda expression?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, what you are saying. Maybe the fact, that for `Func` we have a lot of overloads, like `Funct<TResult>`, `Func<T, TResult>`, `Func<T1, T2, TResult>`, etc can clarify the situation?

Comment: No, sorry. The `Func<T, TResult>` method allows the `foo` method. With expressions we can have return type inference. I was just trying to find a way of using these two facts to find a solution, but couldn't.