# One liner for concatenation of two different lists of objects with the same interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, interface

Consider this simple code:

```
public interface Iinterface { }
public class Foo : Iinterface { }
public class Bar : Iinterface { }
[TestMethod()]
public void Test_Concat()
{
    var bars = new List<Bar>();
    var foos = new List<Foo>();
    // Ok
    IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats1 = bars.Cast<Iinterface>().Concat(foos.Cast<Iinterface>());
    // Compilation error
    IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats2 = bars.Concat(foos);
}
```

I want to concat two lists in one in one line, **and keeping a type safety at compile time**.

If for example, I delete the interface for the class `Foo`, this will still compile, but fail at runtime:

```
public interface Iinterface { }
public class Foo { }
public class Bar : Iinterface { }
[TestMethod()]
public void Test_Concat()
{
    var bars = new List<Bar>();
    var foos = new List<Foo>();
    IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats1 = bars.Cast<Iinterface>().Concat(foos.Cast<Iinterface>());
}
```

If I use `OfType<T>()`, this will not fail at runtime, but I want it to fail at compile time.
The best I could find is to use this 3 line of codes:

```
var list = new List<Iinterface>();
list.AddRange(bars);
list.AddRange(foos);
```

But for something that simple, I want to find a one-liner, and if possible retrieve an `IEnumerable<Iinterface>` instead of a `List<Iinterface>`.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just write your own method?

Since IEnumerable is covariant you only need to specify the base

```
var list= Combine<IInterface>(foos, bars);

private IEnumerable<T> Combine<T>(IEnumerable<T> ListA, IEnumerable<T> ListB)
{
    foreach (T t in ListA)
        yield return t;
    foreach (T t in ListB)
        yield return t;
}
```

Although you might as well just write

```
var list= foos.Concat<IInterface>(bars);
```

Comment: You give the answer by making an error! You don't call the Combine method, but the Concat method of the framework, and it simply works! I just need to add the <Iinterface> to the Concat method.

Comment: @Scorpi0 It's not an error, I just realised after I wrote it that I was re-inventing the wheel! I call the Combine method at the top of the first block

Answer (score 2):

How about making your custom `Concat` extension method version:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T, T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> source, this IEnumerable<T2> other)
        where T1 : T
        where T2 : T
    {
        return source.Cast<T>().Concat(other.Cast<T>());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var items = foos.Concat<Iinterface, Foo, Bar>(bars);
```

It has compile-time safety, and will not compile if any of `Foo` and `Bar` does not implement `Iinterface`.

It should also support differed execution out of the box, because used LINQ methods do.

Comment: Nice idea, too bad the compiler can't inferred the types.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the concat method already did what I want, I juste need to help a little by specifying the return type, because [there is no type inference on return types.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why)

```
    public interface Iinterface { }
    public class Foo : Iinterface { }
    public class Bar : Iinterface { }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void Test_Concat()
    {
        var bars = new List<Bar>();
        var foos = new List<Foo>();

        var list = foos.Concat<Iinterface>(bars);
    }
```

I'm so used to use inference that I forgot that sometimes, compiler need hints!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead:

```
public void Test_Concat2()
{
    IEnumerable<Iinterface> bars = new List<Bar>();
    IEnumerable<Iinterface> foos = new List<Foo>();

    IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats = bars.Concat(foos);
}
```

If you then change the definition `Foo` or `Bar` so it no longer has the interface, you will get a compile-time error.

Comment: Isn't this the same as // Compilation error IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats2 = bars.Concat(foos.AsEnumerable<Iinterface>()); (sorry guys - I put the comment in the wrong place an hour ago).

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in the Cast not the Concat. The declarations are as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second);

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source);
```

In Concat, both enunerables are strongly typed, but Cast does not constrain the source type so the problem occurs at runtime instead of compile time.

Trying a MyCast implementation as follows fails at run time at **(TResult) s**

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MyCast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    var result = (from object s in source select (TResult) s).ToList();
    return result.AsEnumerable();
}
```

If implementing a bit of type checking in a new Cast like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MyCast2<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    where TSource : TResult
{
    var result = (from object s in source select (TResult)s).ToList();
    return result.AsEnumerable();
}
```

then the calling line needs two type params like so

```
IEnumerable<Iinterface> concats3 = bars.Concat(foos.MyCast2<Foo, Iinterface>());
```

and the compiler detects that Foo is not convertible to Iinterface.

Of course, specifying the return type on Concat is more concise.