# How can I define a generic extension method

Tags: c#

I am trying to define an extension method that can return an object of a type defined by the call.

**Desired Use:** `Cat acat = guy.GiveMeYourPet<Cat>();`

**Attempted implementation**

I have no trouble defining generic methods like this:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<T>(Person a) { ... }

Cat acat = GiveMeYourPet<Cat>(guy);
```

or extension methods like this:

```
public static Cat GiveMeYourPetCat<P>(this P self) where P : Person, ... { ... }

Cat acat = guy.GiveMeYourPetCat();
```

But when I try to do what I really want:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<T, P>(this P self) where P : Person, ... { ... }

Cat acat = guy.GiveMeYourPet<Cat>();
```

The compiler expects GiveMeYourPet() to receive 2 type arguments (even though one is implicitly provided by calling the extension method on the object `guy`.

What can I do to make this work?

Note that I've also tried reversing the order in which the parameters are defined, but nothing changes:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<P, T>(this P self)
```

The following call also does not work, because you cannot have a method call in the type specifiation:

```
Cat acat = guy.GiveMeYourPet<guy.GetType(), Cat>();
```

Comment: I'm thinking you'd need to pass in T explicitly as a parameter - otherwise how will the compiler know what to type to return?

Comment: You can't make only some parameters to be implicit. It's all or none.

Comment: I don’t think extension methods work with a generic `this` type; the first solution should work though.

Comment: What would you put into the implementation of such a method? I think it's better to split this into 2 separate 1-type parameterized methods.

Comment: [You can't infer just the return type of generic methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# compiler type inference is not as sophisticated as you might hope. You have to explicitly specify both types in such a method:

```
void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    bool b = i.GiveMeYourPet<bool, int>();
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T GiveMeYourPet<T, P>(this P self)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid specifying both explicitly (and I wouldn't blame you), you might try to change your method to something like:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<T>(this IPetOwner self)
```

(with this interface, you shouldn't even need to know what the real type is; if you do, use `as` or `is`) Or even:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<T>(this object self)
```

(and use `as` or `is`)

If that's not an option, and the real type of `guy` (in your example) is not statically known (e.g. you just have him as an `object`), you'll probably have to use reflection, e.g.:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyExtensions).GetMethod("GiveMeYourPet");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Pet), guy.GetType());
generic.Invoke(guy, null);
```

Comment: Not only that, but what if I don't know the type of 'guy' (or i in this instance), how can I pass in the type of the `this` parameter?

Comment: @Alain `dynamic` is actually quite a useful language feature. Look at my answer.

Comment: I was able to reduce my type constraints on `P` to a single interface and use the technique in your example `public static T GiveMeYourPet<T>(this IPetOwner self)` - thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If something like `guy.GiveMeYour.Pet<Cat>();` would work you can build 2 levels similar to code:

```
public class GiveMeYourBuilder<P>
{
   public P Me {get;set;}
   public T Pet<T>() : where T: new()
   { return new T();}
}

public static PetExtensions 
{
    public GiveMeYourBuilder<P>(this P me)
    {
         return new GiveMeYourBuilder<P> { Me = me;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't partially specify generic arguments, either they are all inferred or you have to specify them all. In this case, the closest you can get is probably to return an intermediate object which carries the generic `Person` type the extension method is called on, and define your `Get` methods on that:

```
public class GiveContext<T> where T : Person
{
    public P MeYourPet<P>() where P : Pet
    {
        return default(P);
    }
}

public static GiveContext<T> Give<T>(this T person) where T : Person
{
    return new GiveContext<T>();
}
```

which you can use like:

```
var p = new Person();
Cat c = p.Give().MeYourPet<Cat>();
```

Comment: If you have a `Person` constraint on `Give<T>`, might as well have a `this Person person` on an extension. I don't feel like it solve anything since it was the first attempt of the original question

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, unfortunately. If the compiler can't figure them **all** out, you need to type out all the type arguments. The C# compiler isn't **that** smart. `dynamic` can help though:

```
public static T GiveMeYourPet<T>(this dynamic self)
{
    //in here check that self meets your constraints using is, as, etc.
}
```