# How to write an extension method/class using two generics?

Tags: c#, generics, automapper, extension-methods

I have created a generic function for my auto mapping.

```
public static TModel ToModel<TContract, TModel>(this TContract contract)
{
   var map = Mapper.Map<TContract, TModel>(contract);

   return map;
}
```

The problem is, I am unable to call my function like this.

```
var map = patient.ToModel();
```

However this one works.

```
public static Model.Patient ToModel(this Contract.Patient patientContract)
{  
    var map = Mapper.Map<Contract.Patient, Model.Patient>(patientContract);

    return map; 
}
```

I am trying to make it generic as the ToModel is repeated over and over for different types.

**I do not want to pass the type on the method.** My problem is trying to figure out how to pass the "type" on the class being that it is static type. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why). Sounds like an XY problem though. You don't seem to _know_ the expected return type at the call site, so you _can't_ provide it. Is that true? Then why do you bother what type you get in return anyway? Can you show how you actually call this code, and why don't you have access to `TModel`?

Comment: Is there not a way to pass in the types on the class level?

Comment: Yes, using `class Foo<T1> { public T1 Bar<T2>(T2 baz) {... } }`.