# Auto Infer type from the usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, c#-7.0

I have a function that reads app settings from the config file.

```
public static T GetValue< T>([CallerMemberName] string settingName = null)
        {
            T settingsValue = default(T);
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName] != null)
                settingsValue = ParserFactory.Parse<T>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName]);
            return settingsValue;
        }
```

Its usage  is something like this :

```
public static string RetailerInvoicePath => AppSettingsReader.GetValue<string>();
```

which is fairly straightforward.  Here I have to specify my type in the GetValue(). But I want my  GetValue to automatically infer the type defined in the property, which means, my new declaration will be

```
 public static string RetailerInvoicePath => AppSettingsReader.GetValue();  // skip type in getvalue
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why).

Comment: Partial "cop-out" : https://dotnetfiddle.net/RwrEKm ?