# Task<T> and Nullability

Tags: c#, .net, task

Hi I've got the following code:

```
    public Task<object?> Do()
    {
        object x = new object();
        return Task.FromResult(x);
    }
```

This code gives me following warning CS8602 Nullability of reference types in value of type Task doesn't match target type Task<object?>

What's even more interesting is the fact that

```
    public Task<object?> Do()
    {
        object? x = new object();
        return Task.FromResult(x);
    }
```

would yield the same error.

The question is why is code analysis complaining about attempting to pass a Task with a stronger constraint as weaker one - I can't figure a scenario where it could go wrong.

Comment: `return Task.FromResult<object?>(x);` works, FWIW

Comment: In *both* cases you're creating and returning a `Task<object>`. The analyzer already knows that `x` is an `object`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Task<object?>` is not a `Task<object>`, in the same sense that a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`. That is to say, the type parameter on `Task` is [invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance). If I do the same experiment on a type with a covariant type parameter, you can see that it works as you'd expect:

```
IEnumerable<object?> Foo() {
    return new List<object>(); // no warnings
}
```

But since nullable reference types only exist at compile time (the CLR doesn't really care), I suppose that's why the compiler only issues a warning and not an error like `List<Dog>` vs `List<Animal>`.

As for the case of

```
object? x = new object();
return Task.FromResult(x);
```

This is because the compiler actually [tracks the null state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#null-state-and-null-tracking) of `x` by doing some static analysis, and sees that `x` is not null at the `Task.FromResult` call. Therefore, it infers that the type argument for the call must be:

```
return Task.FromResult<object>(x);
```

As a result, `Task.FromResult` would return a `Task<object>`, and we have the `Task<object>` vs `Task<object?>` problem again.

Oh, and don't forget that [C# also can't infer `object?` from the return type of the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203643/5133585) :(

These all get rid of the warning:

```
// specify the type parameter explicitly
public Task<object?> Do1()
{
    object? x = new object();
    return Task.FromResult<object?>(x);
}

// infer the static null analysis infer "object?"
public Task<object?> Do2()
{
    object? x = null;
    return Task.FromResult(x);
}

// infer the static null analysis infer "object?"
public Task<object?> Do3(object? x)
{
    return Task.FromResult(x);
}
```

Comment: _"nullable reference types only exist at compile time"_ - yes-and-no: since .NET 6 nullable annotations are exposed via `NullabilityInfoContext` which could be used to (for example) enforce a runtime not-null constraint if a generic type parameter is _not_ nullable, and vice-versa.