# Why can the compiler sometimes not implicitly infer the return type that contains the generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Below is some code in regards to functional progamming (the question itself doesn't relate to functional programming):

```cs
public delegate Exceptional<T> Try<T>();

public static Exceptional<T> Run<T>(this Try<T> @try)
{
   try { return @try(); }
   catch (Exception ex) { return ex; }
}

public struct Exceptional<T>
{
      private Exception? Ex { get; }
      private T? Value { get; }
      
      private bool IsSuccess { get; }
      private bool IsException => !IsSuccess;

      internal Exceptional(Exception ex)
      {
         IsSuccess = false;
         Ex = ex ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ex));
         Value = default;
      }

      internal Exceptional(T value)
      {
         IsSuccess = true;
         Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
         Ex = default;
      }

      public static implicit operator Exceptional<T>(Exception ex) => new (ex);
      public static implicit operator Exceptional<T>(T t) => new (t);

      public TR Match<TR>(Func<Exception, TR> Exception, Func<T, TR> Success)
         => this.IsException ? Exception(Ex!) : Success(Value!);

}

public static class TryExt
{
    public static Try<R> Map<T, R>(this Try<T> @try, Func<T, R> f)
    {
        return () => @try.Run().Match<Exceptional<R>>(ex => ex, t => f(t));
    }

    public static Try<R> Bind<T, R>(this Try<T> @try, Func<T, Try<R>> f)
    {
        return () => @try.Run().Match<Exceptional<R>>(ex => ex, t => f(t).Run());  // doesn't need Match<Exceptional<R>>, can be Match(ex => ex, t => f(t).Run())
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see inside the second method `Bind`, `Exceptional<R>` in Match<Exceptional>(...) is not highlighted, which means I don't need to specify `Exceptional<R>`return type for the Match method.

However, in the first method `Map`,`Exceptional<R>` is needed for the Match method, so why can the compiler detect the return type for `Bind`, but not `Map`, when `Bind` and `Map` method signatures look quite similar?, What is the reason the compiler can infer one but not the other?

Comment: @PalleDue I don't understand why you post this, I did provide the souce code, the image is just for better demo purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty.

Comment: Your Bind method can infer the correct type, because your Run() method returns the correct type from `f(t).Run()`.

Comment: What does the source code for `Match<T>` look like?

Comment: where would you expect it to infer `Exceptional<R>` from in the first case? that isn't part of *any* of the signatures - it isn't going to figure that out without help; in the second case, the `Run()` call provides that info

Comment: As @MarcGravell noted above, the information for your correct return type isn't in any of the method's signatures.  It's not like the compiler can guess what your return type is if it has no information to infer it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey actually the type is present in signature because `Try<T>` (return type of `Map` is basically `Func<Exceptional<R>>`, so here is that type. It can seem that from this info compiler could infer that `Match` inside should return `Exceptional<R>` and then infer the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Match` is defined as:

```
TR Match<TR>(Func<Exception, TR> Exception, Func<T, TR> Success)
```

Then here:

```
public static Try<R> Map<T, R>(this Try<T> @try, Func<T, R> f)
{
    return () => @try.Run().Match(ex => ex, t => f(t));
}
```

first argument to `Match` accepts exception and returns exception. Second argument accepts `T` and returns `R`. `R` is arbitrary type and so compiler cannot find common type `TR` to which both `Exception` and `R` can be converted. Yes there is implicit conversion from any type to `Exceptional<T>` but compiler cannot search all available types for implicit conversions.

In second case

```
public static Try<R> Bind<T, R>(this Try<T> @try, Func<T, Try<R>> f)
{
    return () => @try.Run().Match(ex => ex, t => f(t).Run())
}
```

first argument is the same, but second now returns `Exceptional<R>`. Now there is common type `TR` - that is `Exceptional<R>`, because `Exception` can be implicitly converted to that type. So compiler infers `TR` in `Match` to be `Exceptional<R>` and the rest compiles. The difference is that now compiler can find implicit conversion because one of the types (`Exception`) can be converted to the other (`Exceptional<R>`). In first case there were `R` and `Exception` types which cannot be converted to each other without additional information (that they both can be converted to another type not mentioned anywhere - to `Exceptional<R>`).

Note that, as Eric Lippert describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/5311735) - type information during inference flows from inside to outside only. That means first `Match` types should be inferred and then inference continues to outside (if necessary). As such it does not use the fact that return type of `Map` is `Try<T>` which is basically `Func<Exceptional<R>>`, and so the return type of `Match` should be `Exceptional<R>`.

Comment: I eventually see why it work like this. it is just because the compiler cannot implicitily infer one more level by converting R to its wrapper  like `Wrapper<R>`,hard to 
 believe C# compiler is not smart enough

Comment: @whoisit  I think one piece you miss is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203643/5311735. It applies here because you think it can work because return type of `Match` can be inferred to be `Exceptional<T>`. But it doesn't work like this.